# Can't install s3fs-fuse(yum fuse-devel version issue) and can't install libfuse(./config missing issue)

Tags: docker, centos, fuse, s3fs

I am trying to get s3fs-fuse installed on my Docker container. Here is my Dockerfile so far.

```
FROM    centos:centos6

RUN yum -y update; yum clean all; \
    yum groupinstall -y "Web Server" "MySQL Database" "PHP Support"; \
    service httpd start; \
    chkconfig httpd on;

RUN yum install -y openssh; \
    yum install -y openssh-clients;

ADD ssh/ /root/.ssh/

RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/*; \
    touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts; \
    ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts;

RUN yum install -y git;

RUN yum install -y autoconf libtool gcc libstdc++-devel curl-devel mailcap; \
    yum install -y automake fuse-devel gcc-c++ git libcurl-devel libxml2-devel make openssl-devel;
```

Then after following the instructions at https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse I perform the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse.git
cd s3fs-fuse
./autogen.sh
./configure
```

Then I get this:

```
checking s3fs build with NSS... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for common_lib_checking... configure: error: Package requirements (fuse >= 2.8.4 libcurl >= 7.0 libxml-2.0 >= 2.6) were not met:

Requested 'fuse >= 2.8.4' but version of fuse is 2.8.3

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables common_lib_checking_CFLAGS
and common_lib_checking_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

So, I presume I need to get the right fuse version as `yum fuse-devel` isn't cutting it. So I go to https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse and follow the instructions there with do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse.git;
cd libfuse;
./configure
```

Then I get this issue:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I have been all around the internet and have tried the whole `autoconf` and `autoreconf -i` thing that lead to `m4 directory missing` errors.  I have also tried adding the `--prefix=/your/chosen/directory` to the `./configure --prefix=/your/chosen/directory` command that lead me no where. No luck with a super sad face.

Answer (score 0):

Run `makeconf.sh` in your libfuse clone which creates `configure`.

Comment: Ok it at least feels like a step in the right direction.  However, I get "Running libtoolize..." with a bunch of "/usr/share/aclocal/[somefile]' to `m4/" errors.  Followed by the same result after seeing "Running autoreconf..." in the console before ending the process with "autoreconf: libtoolize failed with exit status: 1"

Comment: Sorry I meant: ... "Running libtoolize..." with a bunch of "can not copy "/usr/share/aclocal/[somefile]' to `m4/" errors